# When a MapReduce job runs what to look for?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, cluster-computing, health-monitoring

I am getting started in Hadoop - and I would like to know

`what all the factors that needs to be looked at when a Map Reduce job(say via Hive or Snapplex) is being triggered to ensure that the cluster is stable and that job does not do any major impact` to the cluster

Where would one look for all these checkpoints and is there any standard thresholds to track against?

Basically a system health check to ensure the MR job we build is clean

Appreciate any insights

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop usually includes a NameNode and JobTracker Webinterface that is used for monitoring purposes.

The NameNode UI gives you an overview of available nodes and the overall cluster capacity as well as dead nodes.

The JobTracker UI gives an overview of the running and failed Jobs and their log outputs.

Default access to the NameNode is via http://localhost:50070/.
And to the Jobtracker: http://localhost:8088 
(This can vary depending on the hadoop distribution you are using)